# USB network adaptor (tethered mobile) not automatically activated

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu desktop (ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64) connecting an Android phone and enabling USB tethering automatically brings up a DHCP configured network adaptor:

> ifconfig

```
ens194u1u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.134  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::c8e8:67ff:fe18:78a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:e8:67:18:78:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11  bytes 1597 (1.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7  bytes 1412 (1.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Attempting the same process on exactly the same hardware but using Ubuntu Server (ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64) (output is hidden from *ifconfig* as the adaptor is down):

> ifconfig -a

```
ens194u1u2: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ca:e8:67:18:78:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

i.e. the adaptor has been detected here but does not appear to have been automatically configured.

While its possible to manually bring this adaptor up by modifying */etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml*:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens192:
            dhcp4: true
        ens194u1u2:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

and then running:

> sudo netplan apply

I'd ideally like the behaviour to match the desktop version, i.e. when tethering the phone the adaptor is automatically configured for DHCP and brought UP.

Can anyone clarify what packages or config I need to change in the server version to achieve that?